# Java stream().filter() cannot find local variable with lamba expression

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, lambda, java-stream

I want to get the amount of a specific product that is in all warehouses. Warehouses contain a list of products. .filter doenst find the local variable "p" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml1zC.png)

I use .map to get a Stream of Lists of products
.flatmap to get a Stream of products and
.filter to compare each product"p" to the parameter of the function

```
public long getQuantityOfProduct(Product product) {
        return warehouses.stream()
            .map(Warehouse::getProducts)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .filter(p -> p.equals(product))
            .count();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like intellij's debugger, streams are notorious for being hard to debug. And the error is expected, unless you declare a breakpoint, which stops inside the lambda (this is supported). Best to starts with jetbrains' help on the topic - [Analyze Java Stream operations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyze-java-stream-operations.html).

Comment: Indeed, that looks like your debugger isn't stopped inside the lambda, and so `p` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a breakpoint **inside** the lambda expression, otherwise the variable will be undefined. Check the [Breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html#set-breakpoints) guide, it is explained how to set a breakpoint only when the lambda is called.

> If the line contains a lambda expression, you can select whether you want to set a regular line breakpoint, or the program should only be suspended when the lambda is called.

It's done like this:

[image: set breakpoint inside lambda]